# permalinks has -2 with post name structure. why?

Tags: permalinks

I have set permalinks structure in my website as post name, then it supposed to come as:

```
http://example.com/newsite/page-name/
```

but it is coming as:

```
http://example.com/newsite/page-name-2/
```

I dont know why the -2 coming with some pages ?
Thanks for help... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably page-name permalink already exists.. Check it in trash as well....

Comment: yes these are in trash...

Comment: delete it then.. and re-update your permalinks.. WordPress checks slugs if it already exists or not if it exists then automatically appends -2 to your slug and makes your permalink ready.

Comment: I deleted them, but problem still same... :(

Comment: Once your slugs are added you need to manually edit the slugs.. Go to the post then just below the title you will find your permalinks and the last part of the permalink is your slug. Click your slug and add your desired name