# Is there a way to regenerate page permalinks without a plugin?

Tags: permalinks

I'm working on a site which has some incorrect permalinks contains 'home-2' e.g.  `http://example.com/home-2/pagetitle/`. I have no way of knowing where `home-2` came from and manually editing the permalink in the page editor only allows me to edit the `pagetitle` portion.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131763/permalinks-has-2-with-post-name-structure-why) seems relevant but refers to the post title and not the portion of the URL I need to change.

So how might this `home-2` situation have occurred. Perhaps a category or parent page? There are no posts or pages in the trash with that name. And how can I remove it without using a plugin such as [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-post-permalinks/) to reset the permalinks?

**UPDATE**

There is a `wp_posts` record in the database for the page with title 'Home' which has the `post_name` field set to 'home-2'.

Answer (score 5):

Simply visiting the permalinks page in wp-admin will reset the permalinks. On that page you also have options which permalinks you want. Check if the home-2/ bit is not prepended there.

Then ofcourse, the obvious is checking that the page 'pagetitle' is not a child of the page 'home-2'. Check your trash for existing pages (but you've already done that).

Do all links have this home-2/ prepended? Or is it only the case on a few pages?

Comment: Thanks :) It's only a few pages but I'd like to understand what is going on rather than recreate the pages. 'Home-2' does not appear on the permalinks settings page and the page 'pagetitle' is a child of 'Home' but NOT 'Home-2'

Answer (score 0):

Is this page a child of another page? If so, you can edit the URL of the parent page.

Note: 99% of the time when I see a "something-2" it's because "something" was already created by another page/post/etc. If you can't find it, check the trash - until you delete it from the trash, WP won't let you use that URL on another page/post/etc.

Comment: Just saw your comment about the page being a child of "Home" - double-check that the URL of Home isn't "home-2". If it is, change it. If it's not, you may need to edit the child page and choose "Home" from the parent drop-down again.

Comment: The Url of Home is not home-2. If I edit a child page and choose Home again, the permalink reverts to home-2. Where is Wordpress generating this 'home-2' if there are no longer two pages called 'home'?

Comment: see also update in question. If a page has a parent, is there any way to remove the parent page name from the permalink entirely?

Comment: not to forget an other classic, slug associated to media. On editing media top right corner in options you can chose to display/edit it's slug. If you had an image 'home.jpg' uploaded, it'll take the slug 'home'